# LLVM IR: Insert new instruction just after its two arguments

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

Let's take an example LLVM IR function `@example_before()`.

```
define void @example_before(i32 %x, i32 %y) {
  %a = and i32 %x, 65535
  %b = lshr i32 %x, 16
  %c = and i32 %y, 65535
  %d = lshr i32 %y, 16
  ret void
}
```

Using LLVM C++ API, the goal is to insert new binary instruction just after both its arguments. I.e. just after the argument that appears in the function later than the other argument.

In the example, let's consider registers `%a` and `%c`. We want to insert `%z = mul i32 %a, %c`. The end result should look like the following `@example_after()`.

```
define void @example_after(i32 %x, i32 %y) {
  %a = and i32 %x, 65535
  %b = lshr i32 %x, 16
  %c = and i32 %y, 65535
  %z = mul i32 %a, %c
  %d = lshr i32 %y, 16
  ret void
}
```

To solve the problem I ended up with a helper function that finds the instruction just after the two provided as arguments. 
The function also requires `DominatorTree`.

```
/// Finds the first instruction after both A and B.
/// A and B are assumed to be either Instruction or Argument.
Instruction *getInstructionAfter(Value *A, Value *B, DominatorTree &DT) {
  Instruction *I = nullptr;

  if (auto AI = dyn_cast<Instruction>(A))
    I = AI->getNextNode();
  else // If Argument use the first instruction in the entry block.
    I = &cast<Argument>(A)->getParent()->front().front();

  auto BI = dyn_cast<Instruction>(B);
  if (BI && DT.dominates(I, BI))
    I = BI->getNextNode(); // After B.

  return I;
}
```

The output of `getInstructionAfter()` can be easily used as the insert point of the new instruction.

```
  IRBuilder<> Builder{getInstructionAfter(X, Y, DT)};
  return Builder.CreateMul(X, Y);
```

However, the `getInstructionAfter()` looks relatively complex comparing with the problem it solves. Are there any simpler solutions for it?

Comment: That's fine, but what's the problem? What have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: I added my current solution. I'm looking for simplification.

Comment: Maybe you can work with instruction iterators? They can be compared to each other, IIRC.

Comment: I've had a similar problem, where I used `BasicBlock::getTerminator()` as insertion point. I happened to know which basic block was last, and inserting earlier would have been prettier but not really all that much better.